# How do Mobile Carriers bill data usage - by byte or by packet?

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, cellular-network

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right place for this question, but I looked in the Stack Exchange Directory and there didn't seem to be one for mobile networks. Feel free to answer by directing me to somewhere more appropriate for this question.

Anyway, I'm working on a project in Android where I'm trying to figure out what the most cost-effective way to send my data is. I'm using TCP Sockets. Essentially, I have a choice between sending a series (say 5) of small (say 100B) payloads or one large payload (1000B). Since I'm not using Nagle's algorithm (which would make the point redundant anyway, right?) I presume that this means that that in the first case I'd be sending 5 packets while in the second case I'd only be sending one packet.

What I'm wondering, is which approach is ultimately going to use more data for my users? The former is technically sending half as much data, but will my users get billed for the packet overhead?

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>(Speaking from the perspective of Swedish carriers, but I suspect the situation is the same worldwide.)</sup>

Carriers typically charge per transferred (sent + received) bytes. Anything else would basically be mean, as the user have very little control over anything else, and limited possibilities to even verify other figures.

Just as with calls, where you sometimes pay for every started minute, they do sometimes have a minimal unit of charge. Few carriers spell it out, but some do, and then it usually says something like "minimal unit of charge is 1 kilobyte".